# Qt C++ creating an Object according to choice in combobox

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Since I am not very experienced in the design of object orientated code, I have the following question:

I have a combobox *cb_GRAN* with 21 entries representing 21 geometries. According to the choice made in *cb_GRAN* I want start different calculations of the surface of my geometry (actually there is more: more complicated calculatins, on/of-switching of LineEdits etc. but to keep it simple let`s just talk about the calculation of the surface. )

To solve this problem I created a class Geometry and 21 Classes (*Geo_1, Geo_2,...Geo_21*) which inherit from Geometry. I also have a virtual method

```
virtual void calculateSurface();
```

To define which class *Geo_x* is to create and to calculate the surface I came up with the following idea:

```
Geometry *GEO;
QVector < Geometry*> qvec_GEO      

qvec_GEO << new Geo_1()<< new Geo_2()<< new Geo_3()<<......  << new Geo_21() ;

GEO =  qvec_GEO[ui->cb_GRAN->currentIndex()];
GEO->calculateSurface();
```

- **Would that be a doable approach to solve my problem or would I run into problems when doing so?**
- **Is it a good idea to create as much as
  21 objects when I would need just one?**

Comment: Why not simply go with "switch (currentIndex()){ case 0: GEO = new Geo_1(); break; case 1: ..." or something similar? Maybe in some function? An even better solution might be something like a switch over the content of your combobox, that is over QString, so that it would still do what it should if the items where to be put in another order. With errors when the item is not recognized. I'm not much in favor of indizes without inherent meaning. Btw, uncommon to name a local variable with all upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:
Your solution will probably work well (only based on information you provided).

Question 2:
You're totally right, creating instance of all your 21 class if you are going to use only 1 or 2 of them is probably an overkill.

You have to find a solution to instantiate only the needed class. Qt provide a Meta-object system you could use for this. Basically, you will have to use the [QMetaType class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html).

First, you have to register the "Geo_N" classes in the meta-object system. You have many solutions to do that, but maybe the best in your case is to use the declarative macro after your class definition:

```
class Geo_1 {
    Q_OBJECT
    void Geo_1();
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geo_1);
```

Please note that Q_OBJECT macro is mandatory if you want to register a class in the meta-object registry.

Then, you will be able to instantiate any registered type dynamically:

```
// The index of selected class (between 1 and 21)
int geoIndex = ui->cb_GRAN->currentIndex();

// Re-build the corresponding class name
QString typeName = "Geo_" + QString::number(geoIndex);

// Retrieve the type ID corresponding to the type name
int typeId = QMetaType::type(typeName.toStdString().c_str());

// Instantiate the corresponding class
Geometry* geo = (Geometry*) QMetaType::construct(typeId);
```

Comment: thank you Antwane for your answer.  I tried it but I get an error for the last line:   " create " is not a member of QMetaType

Comment: What Qt version do you use ?

Comment: I use Qt 4.8.4 with Qt creator 2.8.1

Comment: Try QMetaType::construct(typeId) instead of create (which is the right method for Qt 5)

Comment: I´m still having problems:   I changed QString typeName = "Geo_" + QString::number(geoIndex) because otherwise I got "eo_" for typeName
Then I have a problem in line:  int typeId =  QMetaType::type (typeName.toUtf8().data());   which always returns 0. 
When I want to run a method of my Geo_x-Object, the programm crashes.

Comment: I edited my answer to adapt for Qt4. Now .toStdString().c_str() is used to convert QString to const char *. In addition, please double check you declared your Geo_N classes with Q_OBJECT macro, and you declared the class to MetaType system using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Geo_N) after each class définition

Answer (score 0):

My Approach would be to define a factory class for your geometries

```
class GeoFactory{
  enum GeometryType { GEO_1, GEO_2, ... );
  std::uique_ptr<Geometry> create( GeometryType type );
}
```

And then add the GeometryType to your combobox items in the data role. On the current changed event you just retrieve the GeometryType from the current index and request the corresponding object from the factory.

Personally i always try to keep out Qt from the actual business logic, i just use for UI.